# Does the El Capitan upgrade save the downloaded upgrade files locally?

Tags: software-update, macos

I'm trying to upgrade my Mid-2012 13-inch MacBook Pro to El Capitan. Currently sitting on Yosemite (although both Yosemite and Mavericks are in my Purchased Apps, with Download next to them).

My connection is spotty at best, so I didn't expect to finish the download in a day. However, I noticed that the download doesn't progress very far at all. It says it downloaded say, 7.5 MB of 6.17 GB, then something happens and it says calculating, then it goes back to 2 MB of 6.17 GB. I can pause and resume downloads, but I've never gotten too far before it goes all "calculating" again, and starts back from zero.

It might have something to do with minute disconnections, but does it erase everything and start a new download every time I get disconnected?

On a side note, there's a blue dot on the bar now, where there previously wasn't yesterday, despite having gone back to zero at least five times now, so I'm not sure what exactly is happening.

4:29 PM:
[image: Downloaded 7.7MB]

4:33 PM:
[image: Back to zero]

Comment: I think it ought to 'gather all the bits' until it has a full download - but I've never had a connection poor enough to really stress it. How about investing in a couple of large cups of coffee & see if Starbucks might help you get it through faster?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with an old iMac with a flaky airport card on an otherwise excellent connection the download will pause and resume even over reboots. So, unless the download is damaged, it will pick up where it left off.